# More natural source for a Silverlight game, OpenGL or SDL?

Tags: opengl, silverlight-3.0, sdl

I have two versions of my game.  One was done in pure OpenGL, the other uses SDL.

I want to teach myself Silverlight game programming.  When converting my C++ source into C#, will the OpenGL or SDL version of the game be a more natural starting point?

Comment: what did you end up using for graphics in silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty open ended question, unanswerable question at this point. :(

When you say SDL: are you using SDL-DirectX or SDL-OpenGL?
The DirectX project will be easier to port.

When you say you "used OpenGL" - did you use GTK?  OpenGL ES?  C++ Windows Forms?  You can't *just use* OpenGL.

What version of SDL did you use?
Very old versions do not really support Event driven operation.  Newer versions can be used without any events at all.

So your answer is both are equally good at being equally bad at porting to Silvelright.

Comment: I think he means "pure SDL" in that he used only the 2D operations and SDL_Surface blits. The "pure OpenGL" refers to putting SDL into OpenGL mode and simply using OpenGL 2.1.